# How to call an ionic 1 method from iOS cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a `cordova-plugin` for my `ionic-1` app (iOS Platform). I want to call method that has been created in `js` file of my ionic project from native `iOs` class in `objective-c` file of my `cordova-plugin`.

** Please help to find out how i can achieve this? **

Comment: Do you use **[plugman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plugman)** for developing **cordova plugin**? Through this, you can get default structure.

Comment: yeah I have created via `plugman`, but unfortunately I am unable to figure it out how I can call `JS` method from native `objective-C` code. However, when I call native `objective-c method` through my `JS code` it works perfectly fine. Like `cordova.plugins.MY_IOS_FILE_NAME.MY_METHOD_NAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use cordova `channel` whcih make event protocol between **js** and *native*. You can get example from **[cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/www/inappbrowser.js)**.

Brief explanation of **the link**,

**In javascript code**

import channel library

```
var channel = require('cordova/channel');
```

create channels named after event name

```
function InAppBrowser () {
    this.channels = {
        'loadstart': channel.create('loadstart'),
        'loadstop': channel.create('loadstop'),
        'loaderror': channel.create('loaderror'),
        'exit': channel.create('exit'),
        'customscheme': channel.create('customscheme')
    };
}
```

make add and remove listener function

```
InAppBrowser.prototype = {
    addEventListener: function (eventname, f) {
        if (eventname in this.channels) {
            this.channels[eventname].subscribe(f);
        }
    },
    removeEventListener: function (eventname, f) {
        if (eventname in this.channels) {
            this.channels[eventname].unsubscribe(f);
        }
    },
};
```

register callback in init(optional). you can also do this in your apps.

```
for (var callbackName in callbacks) {
    iab.addEventListener(callbackName, callbacks[callbackName]);
}
```

**In native code**

fire event.

```
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:@{@"type":@"loadstart", @"url":[url absoluteString]}];

[pluginResult setKeepCallback:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.callbackId];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Can you please tell me                                    
                                                                                                            
`CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:@{@"type":@"loadstart", @"url":[url absoluteString]}];

[pluginResult setKeepCallback:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.callbackId];`

what is `[url absoluteString]` ?

Comment: In the case of `inappbrowser`, it means real `url` in internet. In your case, you do not need to send it.

Comment: Thanks @Hyuck Kang. I just added bind listener, and then as you told , sent events through plugin Result and it works fine.