# Call a function outside of window.plugins in TypeScript ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, ionic-framework

I am making an application in ionic and I am using a plugin that is used by calling window.plugins. Specifically it is this plugin.

https://github.com/mike-nelson/cordova-carplay-android-auto

The plugin works fine, but I need to execute functions outside of windows.plugin that are defined in the class.

This is the code and I need to call a function inside the action.

```
window.plugins.carplayAndroidAutoPlugin.registerHandler(function(result){
        if (result  && result.action){
        if (result.action=="handlePlayback"){

            this.actionPlay();

            var itemID = result.param;
            // do your own playback
         }
     }
 }

actionPlay() {
    console.log("actionPlay");
     .......
  }
```

Call a function inside windows.plugin but it says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704934/how-to-call-an-ionic-1-method-from-ios-cordova-plugin

Comment: Yes, this explains how to run an Objective-C command from javascript, but it's not the solution.

The function is located in the TypeScript controller which is outside of the javascript.